# How to echo on array with [data] array?

Tags: php, arrays

I came across this array structure, with a "[data] array" I don't know what it is, and I don't know how to bypass it to print, for example [0]['email']. ['data'][0]['email'] doesn't seem to work either. How can I do this?

```
Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [email] => xxx@xxx.com ) [1] => Array ( [email] => xxx@xxx.com ) ) )
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's my impression your questions are becoming more and more basic. Please consider asking them in the chat instead, or any online forum/bulletin board about php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$varname['data'][0]['email']` should work. Don't you forget to address array variable itself?

Comment: I was forgetting to add ['to'] beforehand as I was already working on a subarray. Anyway this is correct. I'll accept in a few moments